# Is asking for a data source a valid question?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask if someone can point me towards historical data on a particular topic, but I'm not sure if that would be on topic and I'd like feedback on that.

I'd say it should be considered on topic, as it has a specific answer, and would move the site more towards a focus on [political science](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2646/6034), which a past meta-question indicates is desirable.  This sort of question would be a good candidate for a community wiki, as indicated [here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1521/6034).

I will interpret upvotes on this question as "Data requests are okay" and downvotes as "Data requests are not okay".

Comment: What question do you want to ask?

Comment: I'd like to ask for partisanship of congressional delegations by state going back to ~1980.

Comment: If you're going to ask what it sounds like you're asking, I'd lean toward it being too broad, mostly because it doesn't seem like you have a clear problem or "curiosity" to solve.

Comment: That's surprising, because there would be a definite and concise answer to the question in the form "In year[x] and state[y], [a] of [b] house members were of party[z]", where x and y iterate over each of the relevant years.

Comment: You can get that information from Wikipedia.  Not sure if someone already compiled it into something simpler.  As a general rule, questions asking for lists don't work well on Stack Exchange.  This list would be nine hundred lines long (eighteen House elections times fifty states) with three potential data points per line (counts for Republicans, Democrats, and Other).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would absolutely consider that a viable question. This is eminently answerable, and would be a worthwhile problem to solve.